# Merge two /etc/hosts files if IP as the same

Tags: linux, awk, sed, merge

I need merge two /etc/hosts files in unique file only if the IP adress is the same.

File 1 contains:

```
172.27.88.143   node1
172.23.171.42   node2
172.23.171.36   node3
172.27.88.136   node4
172.27.88.137   node5
172.27.88.138   node5
172.27.88.200   node6
```

File 2 contain:

```
172.27.88.200   node6.domain.corp
172.27.88.158   node7.domain.corp
```

The result file must be:

```
172.27.88.143   node1
172.23.171.42   node2
172.23.171.36   node3
172.27.88.136   node4
172.27.88.137   node5
172.27.88.138   node5
172.27.88.200   node6   node6.domain.corp
```

I need to it on Linux systems. That's possible?

Thanks in advace for your time

Comment: Welcome to SO, you could make your IPs as dummy ones, I believe sample data should work here for people's understanding, cheers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $0,a[$1]?"\t" a[$1]:a[$1]}' FILE2 FILE1
```

Comment: @VictorRuiz, cool glad that it worked, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: down voter, please mention the reason for down voting here?

Comment: The awk command works properly with two files, that's really helpful for me. Another question It's possible do the same but with three files? Many thanks @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @VictorRuiz, ues `awk` could multiple files more than 2 too, but you may need to check it how it works(I written this code as per shown example only).

Answer (score 0):

A loop rather than a one-liner, but this should work when `f1` and `f2` are variables for the two `/etc/hosts` files:

```
while read line; do
    ip="$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $2}')"
    secondName="$(grep "${ip}" "${f2}" | awk '{print $2}')"

    echo "${line} ${secondName}"
done < "${f1}"
```

The output contains some trailing space, which can be removed by piping the echo-line through `| sed 's/ \+$//'`.